# How can I use signal and slots to get an id from a qt form, then search for it in a linked list and display the result using another form?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Class with the information that should trigger the the search then display of the other classes after connecting using signal and slots:

```
#include "recruitsearch.h"
#include "ui_recruitsearch.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <QtGui>
#include <string>
#include <QtCore>
using namespace std;
RecruitSearch::RecruitSearch(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RecruitSearch)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

RecruitSearch::~RecruitSearch()
{
    delete ui;
}

void RecruitSearch::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //if(EmployerSearch::ui->buttonBox->clicked();
    if(ui->rfrId->text().isEmpty() || ui->rfrId->text().isNull() || (is_Digit(ui->rfrId->text().toStdString())==false) ){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error", "Please enter a valid RFR id(digits only)");
    }
    else{
        accepted();
        this->close();
    }
}

int RecruitSearch:: getRfrId(){
    return ui->rfrId->text().toInt();
}


bool RecruitSearch::is_Digit( string input){
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
           if (!std::isdigit(input[i]))
               return false;
       }

       return true;
}
```

Class with the display. How would I connect the two slots and use the id from the a first form to  search a linkedlist then display results using another form:

```
#include "rfrform.h"
#include "ui_rfrform.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <QString>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


RfrForm::RfrForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RfrForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

RfrForm::~RfrForm()
{
    delete ui;

}


void RfrForm::setEmpName(string name){
    QString qstr=QString::fromStdString(name);
    ui->EmployerName->setText(qstr);
}

void RfrForm::setAOE(string aoe){
    QString  qstr=QString::fromStdString(aoe);
    ui->AOE->setText(qstr);
}

void RfrForm::setEmpId(int id){
    QString  qstr=QString::number(id);
    ui->EmpId->setText(qstr);
}// end of setId

void RfrForm::setNumOfPos(int num){
    QString qstr=QString::number(num);
    ui->numOfPos->setText(qstr);
}

void RfrForm::setGender(string gen){
    QString qstr=QString::fromStdString(gen);
    ui->gender->setText(qstr);
}

void RfrForm::setMaxRecruits(int max){
    QString qstr=QString::number(max);
    ui->MaxRecruits->setText(qstr);
}


void RfrForm::display(RFR *temp){

    this->show();
}
```

Comment: i have been trying to use signals and slot in ma code and trying to return the class object that i want to display in the second form after it is validated. However signals and slots don't work that way as i have noticed. I need some way of taking an id from a form, then search a linked list and see if its in the list and then display

Comment: i realized this would require some form of event handling, however, i am clueless how to do this with Qt, even with days of trying signal and slots. I am coming from a java (eclipse) environment.

Comment: cloud you please provide only the important code to make it easier to read?

Comment: Can you schematize what you want to achieve? It is not so clear for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of signals and slots in Qt as simply callbacks. For instance, a standard signal/slot may look as follows:

```
....
QAction* act = new QAction(this);
connect(act, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(handleAct()));
....
```

Note that the first parameter is a pointer to the object which will emit the signal (thus, the signal method, `triggered` in this case, must be associated with our sender, in this case `QAction`) and the second parameter is the signal function signature. Similarly, the last two arguments are the pointer for the slot (i.e. the event handler, in this case, the current class) and the function signature for some handler function.

This is for some class which looks like this (note the `Q_OBJECT` macro)

```
class TestMe
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ...
protected slots:
  void handleAct();
};
```

Where the `handleAct()` method is some arbitrary function you design. Now, to answer your question more specifically, we will need more detail on exactly which type of `QWidget` you are using (i.e. so we know which signals it emits). In any case, the basic idea is to catch a particular type of symbol from a particular element, and then handle the information accordingly.

Sometimes, to do a type of information transfer you are looking for, you may need to hold particular pointers to objects as class members so you can easily get a the information in the corresponding `QWidget` (generally a `text()` method or similar).

It is also important to notice, however, that you can override `QWidget` types and created custom signals and slots. So if you have a custom signal which returns an id and a signal which takes an id value as input, you can connect these signals and slots (look into the `emit` functionality)

If you provide some more specific information about the `QWidget` you are using, we may be able to provide you a more specific solution.